# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR uploading image to pinata

Tags: next.js, blockchain, ipfs, pinata

I created a next.js app to upload json

```
   try {
        const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;
        const fileRes = await axios.post(url, formData, {
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data: boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
            pinata_api_key: pinataApiKey,
            pinata_secret_api_key: pinataSecretApiKey,
          },
        });
        console.log("fileRes", fileRes.data);
        // we need to create formData
        return res.status(200).send(fileRes.data);
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.error("errro in uploading image", error.response.data);
```

this is the response I get

```
fileRes {
  IpfsHash: 'QmWb63anLitKNrfiZBiyNBLJGbA57vkFqugJUJvUVvvaKi',
  PinSize: 35672,
  Timestamp: '2022-05-20T17:48:31.784Z'
}
```

I successfully upload the image, It is in pinata files. But I cannot display. I have this error on console.

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

When i click on the link I get this on browser:

[image]

I tried to upload through pinata upload, but I have the same issue.

I tried different images. delete them re-upload them but still error

[image]

### SOLVED

I changed the DNS server to Cloudflare and it works now.

Comment: What image did you upload? Funny I browsed to https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmWb63anLitKNrfiZBiyNBLJGbA57vkFqugJUJvUVvvaKi` and I got served with the screenshot of the browser you posted above.

Comment: @Pandemonium I tried more than 10 different images, all png. They all give me ssl error. I tried using different browsers still same error

Comment: Can you share a different CID from the upload?

Comment: I added a new screenshot

Comment: The first image displays just fine on my Brave browser https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmbTp4n88Yjj931Gg4qz4LYLuCSdQwCv6sn5u8fzs16KsB

Comment: which one? can u send me the link

Comment: It is working now :) all the images are working. was pinata somehow down?

Comment: @Pandemonium I upload new image and json, they dont work here in ny, I clicked on the links on different laptops but links work in europe